Systemd CPUQuota is not working after sudo interactive login
The problem is similar to this one, but there are 2 nuances.

If I switch to user with sudo -u testuser -i then load CPU using stress utility, CPUQuota doesn't take effect.

If I login via SSH as a testuser, run some intensive task and then it works as expected.


My CPUQuota config
/etc/systemd/system.control/user-1003.slice.d/50-CPUQuota.conf
[Slice]
CPUQuota=33%

systemctl show -p DefaultCPUAccounting

DefaultCPUAccounting=yes

Distribution: Debian 12 latest.
Ubuntu 22.04 also affected by this.
How do I debug this issue to get any clues?
P.S. Issue posted on systemd GitHub repo

I've found a solution. You should implement some kind of a user service wrapper around the slice file. Just like it's done here.
After that everything works as expected.
